# Scipy minimize error: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods, scipy

I have defined a Class to minimize a standard function called ***rosen***, in order to minimize ***rosen***, the scipy.minimize function needs to call ***rosen*** repeatedly to minimize it.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np


class LocalMultivariateOptimization:

    def __init__(self, initial_guess_parameters, xtol, method):
        self.xtol = xtol
        self.method = method
        self.x = initial_guess_parameters

    def minimize(self):
        res = minimize(self.rosen(self.x), self.x, method=self.method, options={'xtol': self.xtol, 'disp': True})

    def rosen(self, x):
        return sum(100.0 * (x[1:] - x[:-1] ** 2.0) ** 2.0 + (1 - x[:-1]) ** 2.0)


args0 = np.array([1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.9, 1.2])
xtol = 1e-8
method = 'nelder-mead'

LocalMultivariateOptimizationObject = LocalMultivariateOptimization(args0, xtol, method)
LocalMultivariateOptimizationObject.minimize()
```

results in

> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

This is my first learning attempt at OOP in Python. What am I doing wrong here? I am calling the function instead of sending just the data in minimize(). Which is basically correct.

Comment: I think in `res = minimize(self.rosen(self.x),...` you want `res = minimize(self.rosen,...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [first parameter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) to:

```
scipy.optimize.minimize()
```

is a *callable*.  This bascially means you need to pass a function or a method that can be called by the optimization code.  You however passed:

```
self.rosen(self.x)
```

which has already been called, instead you need:

```
self.rosen
```

In addition your `minimize()` method is not returning anything and should look more like:

```
def minimize(self):
    return minimize(self.rosen, self.x, method=self.method,
                    options={'xtol': self.xtol, 'disp': True})
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining about the callable parameter. However, after changing to the minimize(self) function you gave, it resulted in *TypeError: rosen() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given*

Comment: So I just took your posted code and put in my `minimize()` and there was no exception thrown.

Comment: I am very sorry, I was experimenting, and had some other variations compared to the original code I posted here. Your answer is correct.